# Reading a QJsonDocument without additional copies

Tags: c++, json, qt, io, copy-elision

I'm trying to read a `QJsonDocument`, and I want to minimize the number of copies made. When I read example code by others, it looks like they are making two or three copies of the data just to read it. Part of the problem is that I don't know what's a copy of the document and what's essentially a pointer to the document.

The documentation hasn't been much help. Here's how I've imagined it my head, but I don't think this is accurate:

- `QJsonDocument` is like a top level `QJsonObject` that provides document-level member functions. It stores the entire document.
- `QJsonObject` is an ordered tree-like object where nodes correspond to keys. I think a `QJsonObject` keeps a copy of the section of the document it points to, even though that would be inefficient.
- `QJsonValueRef` is like a reference to a `QJsonObject`, although I can't tell why iterators aren't used instead of `QJsonValueRef`. It also seems difficult to use `QJsonValueRef` without copying the contents of the `QJsonObject`.

Suppose we want to read "Street", "City", and "County" from this json:

```
{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "MiddleName": null,
    "Age": 43,

    "Address": {
        "Street": "Downing Street 10",
        "City": "London",
        "Country": "Great Britain"
    },
    "Phone numbers": [
        "+44 1234567",
        "+44 2345678"
    ]
    "Valid":true,
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61286325) stackoverflow answer provides a solution below. I have numbered some lines for my question.

```
QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonDoc.object(); // (1)
QTextStream textStream(stdout);

QJsonValue jsonVal = jsonObj.value(QString("Address")); // (2)
QJsonObject jsonItemObj = jsonVal.toObject(); // (3)

QJsonValue jsonSubVal;

jsonSubVal = jsonItemObj["Street"]; // (4)
textStream << jsonSubVal.toString() << endl; // (5)

jsonSubVal = jsonItemObj["City"];
textStream << jsonSubVal.toString() << endl;

jsonSubVal = jsonItemObj["Country"];
textStream << jsonSubVal.toString() << endl;
```

Out of (1)-(5), which are copies? Is there a way to eliminate these copies? (In line (5), I am referring to `jsonSubVal.toString()` rather than `textStream <<`.)

Answer (score 1):

[`value()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsonobject.html#value) returns by value so will always be a copy.

[`operator[]`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsonobject.html#operator-5b-5d-1) returns a reference when used on a non-const object but by value when called on a const object. Note that the non-const version will modify the object if the requested key doesn't exist. Also note that by assigning the result of the operator to `QJsonValue` you are forcing it to copy, use `QJsonValueRef` instead.

To avoid copies you can use [`find`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsonobject.html#find) which returns iterators.

Not however that once you have a `QJsonValueRef` there doesn't seem to be a way to get to the contained object without making a copy see [How to change QJsonObject value in a QJson hierarchy without using copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034336/how-to-change-qjsonobject-value-in-a-qjson-hierarchy-without-using-copies)

You might want to find a better JSON library if avoiding copying is important to you.

Comment: Suppose I use ```find``` on a ```QJsonObject``` to get ```QJsonObject::iterator iter```. I now want to search for a key in the ```QJsonObject``` pointed to by that iterator. What do I do now? I can call ```iter.value()``` or ```*iter``` to get a ```QJsonValueRef```, but what then? How do I call ```find``` again?

Comment: @Bobby Have you tried it? It should work, `QJsonValueRef` is essentially the same as `QJsonObject`

Comment: I have tried it. ```QJsonValueRef``` has no member function ```QJsonValueRef::find()``` or dereference operator. I also couldn't find anything like that looking in the ```QJsonValue.h``` header. I could call ```operator[]``` or one of the ```.toX()``` functions, but that makes a copy I believe.

Comment: As an aside, I did ctrl + f for "find" in Qt's [Save Game Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore-serialization-savegame-example.html) and there is not a single use of ```find```. I'm not saying ```find``` is wrong, just pointing out how hard it is to find correct usage.

Comment: Hmm, ok, looks like it's not possible, maybe you should find a better library